# In gitweb, how can I set the parent when doing a diff on a merged commit?

Tags: git, gitweb

Please note, this question is about GITWEB, not git. I know how to do this in git, but I would like to be able to perform it in gitweb so I can easily show my changes to people I work with.

If I have a tree that looks like this:

```
*--C--D     master
 \     \ 
  *-A---B   proj-1
        ^
        merge commit, has 2 parents
```

I would like to be able to see the differences between B and D. This should show the changes of A & B vs C & D. However, when I use git web (specifying the commit hash), it just shows me what's in D. Is there any way to set the parent when using commitdiff on a merge commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I may have the answer... Try just adding/changing the hp parameter to the new parent SHA in the URL:

```
https://gitweb.server.com/?p=REPONAME;a=commitdiff;h=SHA;hp=PARENTSHA
```

This works on my gitweb server.